# How to automatically sync the contents of a local folder with the contents of a ftp folder?

Tags: sync, ftp

After searching everywhere I have not managed to find a specific answer for my question.

On Windows there is an application called [FTPbox](http://ftpbox.org/) that will automatically sync a local folder with an ftp one every set period of time.

My question is, how do I achieve the same thing using Ubuntu? The main thing is here that I dont want to have to do it manually. It needs to be a totally automatic process with no human intervention required (obviously I will have to set this up if that classes as human intervention LOL).

Many thanks in anticipation for helpful answers.

-Edward

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**First solution**

Install `lftp`

```
sudo apt-get install lftp
```

after that create script

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='mysite.com'
USER='myuser'
PASS='myuser'
TARGETFOLDER='/new'
SOURCEFOLDER='/home/myuser/backups'
 
lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```

Save it on some place with name `upload.sh`. Give it `+x` permission.

```
sudo chmod +x /path_to_script/upload.sh
```

Setup `crontab` to run this command on every `x` period of time

For editing crontab run

```
crontab -e
```

For running command on every 5 min code is

```
 */5 * * * * /path_to_script/upload.sh
```

on every hour

```
 0 */1 * * * /path_to_script/upload.sh
```

to run on 4 am

```
 0 4 * * * /path_to_script/upload.sh
```

**Solution two**

Create a small and easy script called `lftp-script` that `LFTP` can read:

```
open ftp://username:password@website.com
mirror --reverse -v --only-newer /home/local/path/ /website.com/public_html/
```

Finally you can run `LFTP` and start the synchronisation. Set crontab like I write but put command

```
lftp -f /path/to/lftp-script
```

something like this

```
 */5 * * * * lftp -f /path/to/lftp-script
```

**Solution three**

Install `curlftpfs`

```
sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
```

you need to do in order to mount ftp locally is to to run these commands
create dir witch will be sync-ed

```
mkdir hostr
```

mount remote ftp dir to local

```
sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com host
```

*user:pass* is the username and password to log into ftp account.

You can add `curlftpfs` to `fstab` for automatic mounting by using this line :

```
curlftpfs#user:pass@ftp.example.com /mnt/host fuse rw,uid=500,user,noauto 0 0
```

Comment: TARGETFOLDER='/new' = folder on ftp?
SOURCEFOLDER='/home/myuser/backups' = local folder with files i want to upload?

Comment: yes and yes. :)

Comment: saying this Transferring file `Untitled 1.odt'                            
mirror: /home/edward/bl3/bl2/bl1/Untitled 1.odt: No such file or directory Unknown command `;'

Comment: Based on ftp server path meybe not only `/new` folder. Check both path.

Comment: If you create folder in `source folder` on local, that folder must be sync-ed with ftp folder.

Comment: Very neat! Is it possible to move the files? I.e. remove files that has already been uploaded? Need some way of knowing whether a file has been uploaded or not. Also; what happens if connection are lost in the different solutions? Will it retry to connect and how does one get notified?